# DateInput yields empty strings for allowEmpty inputs

Tags: react-admin

One hiccup we ran into with React Admin was around date fields for a table. We're just using the stock ra-data-json-server package. Our backend should be receiving a null value for an empty date, but it comes through as a blank string instead. What's the best approach for handling this?

- Creating a custom DateInput component that yields null for an empty date.
- Creating a custom data provider that would convert an empty string to null (not sure if it would have enough context to do this, though).
- Something else I haven't thought of.

I'm not keen on doing the translation at the API end, since I'd like to keep the API clean and only allow for a valid date or a null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform the input value using the parse / format functions:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-record